# Spring Boot RestTemplate Basic Authentication using RestTemplateBuilder

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot

In Spring Boot I'm trying to create a RestTemplate which will use basic authentication using

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
    builder.basicAuthorization("username", "password");
    RestTemplate template = builder.build();
    return template;
}
```

I then inject the RestTemplate in my service class as

```
@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;
```

However, my requests fail with a 401 unauthorized exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 401 Unauthorized
```

Using another REST Client (Postman) the requests to the same URL succeeds so I assume the basic authentication is not working correctly. From the debug output it looks as if the authentication header is not being set. What will make this work?

Comment: go debug and see if it sets the header properly, my guess would be you have more resttemplate in your spring context.

Comment: There is just one RestTemplate in the spring context.

Comment: share your client code..How you are sending the request

Comment: The problem is your configuration, the `basicAuthorization` is basically a factory method for a **new `RestTemplateBuilder`** but you aren't using that newly created instance. Do `return builder.basicAuthorization("username", "password").build();` instead of what you have now (or reuse the newly created instance).

Answer (score 21):

The problem is that you are using the `RestTemplateBuilder` in a wrong way. The `RestTemplateBuilder` is immutable. So when doing [`builder.basicAuthorization("username", "password")`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/web/client/RestTemplateBuilder.java#L383) you actually get a new instance, with a `BasicAuthorizationInterceptor` added and configured, of the `RestTemplateBuilder`. (this applies to all configuration methods of the `RestTemplateBuilder` they all create a fresh copied instance).

However your code is discarding that specifically configured instance and you are basically using the non secured default `RestTemplateBuilder`.

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
    builder.basicAuthorization("username", "password");
    RestTemplate template = builder.build();
    return template;
}
```

This code should be replaced with something like this.

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
    return builder.basicAuthorization("username", "password").build();
}
```

Which will use the specifically configured instance.

Comment: Thanks alot, yes that was the problem.

Comment: basicAuthorization deprecated since 2.1.0 in favor basicAuthentication(String username, String password)

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to create the RestTemplate as follows:

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
    RestTemplate template = builder.build();
    template.setMessageConverters(
        Arrays.asList(
            new FormHttpMessageConverter(),
            new StringHttpMessageConverter()
        )
    );
    template.getInterceptors().add(new BasicAuthorizationInterceptor("username", "password"));

    return template;
}
```