# RestTemplate returns 401 while Postman succeeds

Tags: java, spring, rest, ssl, resttemplate

I am trying to do post request to a rest service (https).
Everything works fine in postman although RestTemplate.exchange always returns 401 - unauthorized. 
The body and the headers are the same.

```
 HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
 httpHeaders.add("client_id", clientId);
 httpHeaders.add("api_key",  authToken); 
// httpHeaders.add("Authorization", "Basic " + authToken); - also tried

 HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(request, httpHeaders);
 return restTemplate.exchange(getUrl(), httpMethod, requestEntity, responseType).getBody();
```

I've tried to skip ssl verification, also tried this solution: [Spring Boot RestTemplate Basic Authentication using RestTemplateBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45670955/spring-boot-resttemplate-basic-authentication-using-resttemplatebuilder), it doesn't help. 
Any ideas what I am missing?

Comment: sometimes its the lack of User-Agent header or lack of the Keep-Alive header https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keepalive

Comment: Can you explain or give me more details ?

Comment: How are the credentials set within the RestTemplate?  Post the code that is not working.

Comment: Post a code snippet showing how your request is made on RestTemplate and also provide an image of your postman request.

Comment: @andreybleme I updated my question

Comment: @AndrewS it's authToken  - base64 encoding of user:password

Comment: use Postman developer tools to see that actual request build by postman

Comment: I doubt the request is the same, else the result would be the same. Computers are quite deterministic in that.

Comment: @M.Deinum I realize that, that's why I am wondering, may be rest template transforms the request somehow without me noticing it

Comment: Your code seems right. Debug it and pay attention to the values of the api_key and client_id, make sure they are the same as the request that you're sending using postman.

Comment: @andreybleme literally copy-paste=)

Comment: You didn't get me. I meant that the value of your api_key and client_id may be different when you're performing your request thought RestTemplate. You URL may also be different. Make sure these values are right at execution time.

Comment: @andreybleme Yes, They are the same